# Linking Bitbucket to Youtrack

Tags: bitbucket, youtrack

I'm trying to link issues in commit messages from Bitbucket to Youtrack, but can't find proper solution.

I have for ex. commit message "CORE-214 adding foreign currency" and want to make CORE-214 link to our Youtrack as described here - https://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/06/18/use-custom-regex-to-link-anywhere-on-bitbucket/

So I create new custom link in Repository / Settings / Links using Add a custom link:

```
Replacement URL: https://ouryoutrack.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/\1
Raw regex: CORE-\d+
```

However no links are showing in commit messages. We were using JIRA links integration before and everything was working fine, but that was configured using Add a repository link to JIRA feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\1` part of the replacement regex is meant to insert a [captured group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) from the regular expression. Your regex doesn't include any capture groups.

Try this instead: `(CORE-\d+)`.